# how to make my program skip the "on_message" function if false (discord.py rewrite)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make my bot be able to tag members when a certain command is written, but the only way I was able to do that is with a on_message command which seems to just stop my program whether false or true, even if it activates when true

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('m-example'):
        await message.channel.send('<' + '@' + '{}' .format(message.author.id) +'>' + ' example!')
```

Comment: Do you have multiple `on_message` events in your code?

Comment: What do you mean by stop the program, do the commands not work or is the script exiting with an error?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming, that by stopping the program you meant that the bot commands don't work. This is because your on_message overrides discord.py's default on_message which processes your commands. Here is what you need to do

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.wait_until_ready()
   # do stuff here
   await client.process_commands(message)
```

`wait_until_ready()` makes sure that your bot does not do anything till it is connected and ready
`process_commands` tells discord.py to process the message as a command

### References:

- [wait_until_ready](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_until_ready#discord.Client.wait_until_ready)
- [process_commands](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=process_commands#discord.ext.commands.Bot.process_commands)

### Extra tips:

- You can know if your bot's script has stopped or if something else is wrong has happened by checking if the bot is online/ has the status you used when starting it.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to put `await client.process_commands(message)` in your script for your other commands to work.
2. I recommend using `message.author.mention` instead of `'<' + '@' + '{}' .format(message.author.id) +'>'` which is much easier.

So your script should look like this;

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await client.process_commands(message)
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('m-example'):
        await message.channel.send(message.author.mention + ' example!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you can do mentioning someone **much** easier, for this example with `message.author.mention`, secondly I don't know what problem you have but maybe this now works:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id != bot.user.id: 
        if message.content.startswith('m-example'):
            await message.channel.send(f"{message.author.mention} example!")
```